# CPU usage in animation playback

Tags: animation, frame-rate

im new to the blender scene.
I have a ryzen 7 5800H CPU but am getting 1.4 fps while on animation playback. Blender is also using about 50% of the CPU while in playback. is there any way to improve framerate? should i overclock when using the playback feature?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eevee or Cycles?